# Callout from Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

I have a requirement with the following functionality:

1. Before the Opp stage gets updated to Closed-Won on ever opp I should be able to push the opp info to an external REST webservice URL as JSON format.
2. After successfully pushed I will get a JSON response with an account Id and status message with this I need to update the Opportunity.

I was not able to look my trigger in the debug lo is something in my trigger?I'm not able to make call to the URL? How to handle the request and response and map it to the opp?

**Here is the Trigger:**

```
trigger OppUpdate on Opportunity (before insert,before update) {
    for (Opportunity Opp : Trigger.new) {
        if (Opp.StageName=='ClosedWon') {
            opptycall.post(JSON.serializePretty(Trigger.new));
            system.debug(JSON.serializePretty(Trigger.new));
            system.debug(JSON.serialize(trigger.new));
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my class:**

```
public class opptycall {@future(callout = true)
    public static void post(id opptyid) {
        //Construct HTTP request and response
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        //Http http = new Http();        

        //Construct Authorization and Content header
        //request.setHeader('Authorization', getBasicAuthHeader('test','test'));
        //req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        //Construct Endpoint
        String endpoint = 'https://test.com';

        //Set Method and Endpoint and Body
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        //json string in body 
        system.debug('Opportunity ID' + opptyid);
        Opportunity Op = [select id, Name, Stagename, Account.Name from opportunity where stagename = 'Closed-Won'
        and id = : opptyid];
        System.debug('with pretty' + JSON.serializePretty(Op));
        system.debug('without pretty' + JSON.serialize(Op));
        String JsonString = JSON.serializePretty(Op);
        req.setBody(JsonString);
        system.debug(JsonString);

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            JSONParser par = JSONParser.parse(response.getBody());
            System.debug('-par.message.Opportunity-' + par.message.Opportunity);
            for (JSONParser.Opportuntiy Opp: par.message.Opportuntiy) {
                Opp.add(new Opportunity(
                Id = par.message.Opportuntiy.Id,
                Status = par.message.Opportuntiy.status,
                Description = par.message.Opportuntiy.description));
                update opp Id;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception in debug logs

Comment: Could  you provide some more details, like what I understand of error do you get?

Comment: can you make sure that url in added in remote site settings

Comment: You should verify the `string` you are using for `StageName`. You've got both `ClosedWon` and `Closed-Won` in your code. Since this field is a picklist and can be changed by the user and more importantly multiple opportunity stage values can represent a closed opportunity, you might consider querying the `OpportunityStage` object for the StageName and check the values of `isClosed` and `isWon` and drive your logic from that data.

Comment: One other problem is that you are passing a JSON string to `opptycall.post` when it is expecting an ID.

Comment: echoing @KeithC, you are passing a JSON string that is an array of Trigger.new to a handler that is expecting a single opportunityId

Comment: Trigger MySparefootOppUpdate on Opportunity (before insert,before      update) { 
  for (Opportunity Opp : Trigger.new) {                                                               if (Opp.isWon) {
 
    opptycall.Oppupdate(Opp.Id);
    System.debug('Opp.Id');
    }
  }
}

Comment: nevertheless, you are going to hit this limit: http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_apex_limits_callout_future.htm for data loader use cases - time for the dan appleman async apex pattern

Answer (score 6):

If you care calling this trigger on a Before Insert, there is not ID for the object before insert.  Before update is okay, but this won't work on before insert. You will want to do after insert.

As pointed out by someone else, you are passing in a JSON string when the opptycall.post is expecting an ID type.   You can pass in `Trigger.new.[0].Id`.  Be careful here, your code is not bulkified so this won't behave as expected when you bulkupdate.

```
trigger OppUpdate on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    for (Opportunity Opp : Trigger.new) {
        if (Opp.StageName == 'ClosedWon') {
            opptycall.post(JSON.serializePretty(Trigger.new));

            system.debug(JSON.serializePretty(Trigger.new));
            system.debug(JSON.serialize(trigger.new));
        }
    }
}
```

The other thing you want to be aware of is that your code with the `@future` call means that the opportunity is getting updated and saved and then the callout is happening after that record is saved.  Your callout is updating the opportunity after it gets a response.   Small detail here, but it might help you with troubleshooting.   In your log files, you'll see a FutureHandler log that looks like this.  That is where you'll see the debug information:

[image: futurehandler log file]

I'm using the developerconsole to view the logs.

Answer (score 1):

In `opptycall.post`, you have `if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) { ... }` but it should be `if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) { ... }`.

You have a few references to `response` and those all need to be changed to `res`.

Answer (score 0):

You should also bulkify the trigger - it looks like your code will run a query for every changed Opportunity id, which may hit govenor limits. I believe it's best practice to build out a list of ids in the trigger:

```
trigger OppUpdate on Opportunity (before insert,before update) {
    List<String> opIds = new List<String>();
    for (Opportunity Opp : Trigger.new) {
      if (Opp.StageName=='ClosedWon') {
        opIds.add(Opp.Id);
        system.debug(JSON.serializePretty(Trigger.new));
        system.debug(JSON.serialize(trigger.new));
    }
    opptycall.post(opIds);
}
```

then pass that list of ids to your to pass to your method sending the callout:

```
opptycall.post(List<String> opids) {
   ...
```

and then loop through the ids there:

```
<List>Opportunity Ops = [select id, Name, Stagename, Account.Name from opportunity where id in :opIds];
for (Opportunity op : Ops) {
     // do call out
}
```